# setState doesn't render (fetch in a ftech)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got this class :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Card from './Card';

class Deck extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      deck: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('URL1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(deck => {
        fetch(`URL2`)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(({ cards }) => {
            this.setState(state => {
              state.deck = cards;
            });
            this.forceUpdate();
          });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { deck } = this.state;
    return deck.map((card, i) => <Card card={card} key={this.state.deck[i].code} />);
  }
}

export default Deck;
```

Everything works fine, except the setState doesn't launch any render (that's why there is a forceUpdate()).
Is there anything to know about fetch and setState that I missed here ?

Comment: Does this update if you return `true` from `shouldComponentUpdate`?

Comment: You aren't using the fetched `deck` in your `setState()`; are you positive that the state actually changes? Also, you can use `key={card.code}`

Comment: I'm not a React user, but don't you return the new state in the setState..  eg..  `this.setState(state => { return { deck: cards }})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing a function to `setState`, you must return the state that you want to change:

```
this.setState(state => {
  return { deck: cards };
});
```

This is analogous to doing the following (except the above is [batched](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-passing-an-object-or-a-function-in-setstate)):

```
this.setState({ deck: cards });
```

The important thing to know is that the object `{ deck: cards }` in both examples is merged onto the existing state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `this.setState()` to update state. Don't mutate state. Also `promises` are to make code clean and less nested. You can return a value/promise from previous `then` callback and then chain a new `then` outside of it which will get returned value from last then callback or value that will be returned after resolving returned promise.

```js
class Deck extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      deck: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     let _this = this;
    return fetch('URL1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(deck => fetch(`URL2`))
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(({ cards }) => {
        this.setState(state => {
          _this.setState({ deck: cards });
        });
        //_this.forceUpdate();
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { deck } = this.state;
    return deck.map((card, i) => <Card card={card} key={this.state.deck[i].code} />);
  }
}

export default Deck;
```

Comment: Your solution would be much cleaner without the unnecessary nesting: this.setState({deck: cards});.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Answer to OP question is `this.setState({deck: cards});` and other than that are just improvements.

Answer (score -1):

Let's look at how you call `setState()`:

```
this.setState(state => {
  state.deck = cards;
});
```

This assigns a value to the local variable `state`, but does not update the state of the component. The correct way to alter state with a callback is to return the new state:

```
this.setState(state => {
  return {deck: cards};
});
```

Since you do not calculate the new state from the previous state, this can be simplified without the use of a callback:

```
this.setState({deck: cards});
```